# Will the fields of Solr Documents only be saved as lists?

Tags: python, django, solr

I have created a document in Solr and provided some data in it. The data are saved as list in the document as show below:

```
"response":{"numFound":2,"start":0,"docs":[
 {
        "ad_id":[1],
        "hash":["1"],
        "campaign_id":["1"],
        "fingerprint":[1],
        "id":"44c458eb-0674-4fce-ad54-e16234c868bf",
        "_version_":1577315711035899904}]
  }}
```

I am currently providing a static data to Solr form django like below:

```
solr.add([
        {
            "hash": "1",
            "ad_id": "1",
            "campaign_id": "1",
            "fingerprint": "1",
            }
    ])
```

I want the data to be saved as below (not in list form):

```
"response":{"numFound":2,"start":0,"docs":[
     {
            "ad_id":"1",
            "hash":"1",
            "campaign_id":"1",
            "fingerprint":"1",
            "id":"44c458eb-0674-4fce-ad54-e16234c868bf",
            "_version_":1577315711035899904}]
      }}
```

Is it possible? If it is, how can I send my data so that it wont ba saved as list?

Answer (score 2):

Check all these field `"ad_id","hash","campaign_id","fingerprint",`
declaration  in your schema.xml file if `multivalued` is set to true

ex:

```
<field name="ad_id" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

change to `multivalued="false"` if you are sure that all those fields will have single value in one document.

**Note** : if multivalued="false", you cannot store multiple values to that field. After schema modification restart/reload solr and reindex documents.

Comment: since I am new to Solr can you please tell me where is the schema.xml file

Comment: I hope you using latest version of solr. ex:  `solr-6.1.0/server/solr/collection_name/conf/managed-schema`

Comment: if you are using older version ex: 5.3.1 it will be with name schema.xml `solr-5.3.1/server/solr/collection_name/conf/schema.ml` recent releases of solr, file name is changed to managed-schema.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the field type in solr schema for this. 
Look for multivalued in your field types. If you are using dynamic fields type, i would recommend define new set of fields based on your schema.